# Restsharp polly retry policy based on status

Tags: c#, restsharp, http-status-codes, polly, retry-logic

I am trying to manipulate polly retry policy based on response status code.
If status code is 500, I need to retry after 3 minutes else I need to retry after 2, 4 seconds.
I have something like this right now,

```
.OrResult<RestResponse>(
    (response) => {
        return !response.IsSuccessful || response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
    })
.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) })
```

I can possibly add `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)` but I only want to do it if the response status code is 500.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `WaitAndRetryAsync` has [several overloads](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryTResultSyntax.cs#L327). In your case you have used one which accepts an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>` which defines the retry count and the delays between each attempt.

There are overloads which allows you to define the `sleepDurations` dynamically. In those cases you have to provide a `sleepDurationProvider`.

In the bellow example I've used [this overload](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryTResultSyntax.cs#L652):

```
 public static AsyncRetryPolicy<TResult> WaitAndRetryAsync<TResult>(
       this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, 
       int retryCount,
       Func<int, DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, 
       Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync)
```

- `int retryCount`: At most how many retry attempts should be issued
- `Func<int, DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider`: A user-defined function which receives the number of retry attempt, the result of the attempt, a context and anticipates a `TimeSpan` in return
- `Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync`: A user-defined function which is called if the policy should be triggered but before the sleep

With this you can achieve the desired behaviour:

```
.WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3, 
    sleepDurationProvider: (int retryCount, DelegateResult<RestResponse> response, Context ctx) =>
{
    if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    return retryCount switch
    {
        1 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        2 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        3 => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) //It won't be used due to the retryCount
    };
}, onRetryAsync: (_, __, ___, ____) => Task.CompletedTask);
```

- If the response's status code is 500 then return with a 3 minutes sleep duration

  - For every other cases decide the sleep duration based on the number of attempt
- The `onRetryAsync` delegate needs to be defined otherwise the compiler will not find this overload